# AskTimeoutException on submit but Flow starts successfully

Tags: apache-flink

Flink 1.9.1 is running standalone (on AWS ECS) with 1 JobManager and 3 TaskManager.

On submitting a JAR to start a Flow per the [Flink REST API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html) (Having `JAR_ID`, `PARALLELISM` & `PROGRAM_ARG` properly set) via

```
curl -X POST "http://jobmanager:8081/jars/${JAR_ID}/run?parallelism=${PARALLELISM}&programArg=${PROGRAM_ARG}"
```

we get the status code `500` this body/exception (replaced '\n' with real newlines for readability):

```
{"errors":["Internal server error.","<Exception on server side:
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/dispatcher#-965140037]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:650)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:870)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:103)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:868)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

End of exception on server side>"]}
```

But the Flow is *always* `CREATED` successfully and starts `RUNNING` without any problems. I have seen the submit sometimes *not* to through the error and start running.

The flow is always visible via WebUI and the REST API afterward submitting.

All ports that I could find in the documentation have been configured (on the JobManager & TaskManager respectively) and are open in the firewall (AWS security groups). 
Also the default ephemeral port range `49153` - `65535` is open between the JobManager and TaskManager nodes:

```
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
blob.server.port: 6124
taskmanager.data.port: 6125
taskmanager.rpc.port: 6126
metrics.internal.query-service.port: 6127
resourcemanager.rpc.port: 6128
rest.port: 8081
queryable-state.server.ports: 9067
queryable-state.proxy.ports: 9069
metrics.reporter.prometheus.port: 9160
```

Which ports are we missing to configure/open up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you posted indicates that the answer of an RPC was not sent within a timeout. There are two RPCs to the Dispatcher in `JarRunHandler`:

1. BlobServer port lookup to upload the user Jar to the BlobServer [1]
2. JobGraph submission [2]

Because your job eventually runs despite of the error, I think that all RPCs arrive at the receiving side but the Acknowledge of the latter RPC is not sent back.
I do not think that your problem is related to firewall settings because the first RPC actually succeeds. However, without looking into the JobManager logs, it is difficult to further debug the issue.

[1] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.9.1/flink-runtime-web/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/webmonitor/handlers/JarRunHandler.java#L88

[2] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.9.1/flink-runtime-web/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/webmonitor/handlers/JarRunHandler.java#L104